# Ubuntu 18.04 server hangs on startup when enabling iptables

Tags: boot, iptables, ubuntu-18.04, iscsi

After enabling iptables, with the following very basic configuration:

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1 -d 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

, the server hangs on startup at the following message:

```
Loading iSCSI transport class v2.0-870.
iscsi: registered transport (tcp)
iscsi: registered transport (iser)
```

Whenever I change back `iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT` the server starts normally.

Any suggestion why, and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You drop everything in INPUT not going from loopbak to loopback or DNS iSCSI cannot make connection (it is using IP connection to iSCSI device which is normally not on loopback).

Comment: I don't understand what kind of iSCSI connections could be needed at startup.
Do you know how I could track this or somehow enable it? What else Interface or IPs are they using?

Comment: @linzus do You use iSCSI ? I had to investigate what exactly the driver is doing.. I assume it should not hang if You have no iSCSI devices in use but not sure.. I think default Port for iSCSI is 3260.